# Chaining of Batch getting counted against API Requests, Last 24 Hours

Tags: apex, api, batch

This is strange for me and a new information to me. But calling a batch or recursively calling a batch is contributing to API Requests of org.

[image]

I did test this in my own dev org, where no external apis are being hit and no scheduled job is firing a callout.

Everytime I refresh the screen `API requests` increases by 1-2, and after sometime it does not increase, after that I wrote a recursive batch to prove my theory.

```
global class RiderInsertInBatch implements Database.Batchable<Integer>{
    global Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext info){
        return new IntegerIterator(1);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext info, List<Integer> scope){
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info){
        Database.executeBatch(new RiderInsertInBatch());
    }
}
```

And to my surprise the API requests increased by 500 in less than few minutes.
I am not sure why, but is this because `Batch` or any async operation happens on another server outside of the org. So to execute a batch the other server might be firing a `REST`/`POST` call to org to execute it.

Comment: It could be a case that developer console is using API limits -> https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxbZAAQ

Comment: But that should  be just one api call to call the batch once. Right?

Comment: Not if it is fetching an API logs

Comment: Anyways  its not called from developer console. its from workbench

Comment: I agree with @kurunve, something else is going on. Most likely something monitoring debug logs. Developer Console uses a load of API to show you the latest logs. Maybe your IDE could be doing it? The API Usage Report will probably give you more info https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000336267&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1

Comment: have you taken a look at your API Calls Made Within Last 7 Days [report](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000326126&type=1&mode=1) to see if there's any info in the client Id?

Comment: I tried in my developer edition org, so these reports are not available here. Any other way to fetch this report?

Comment: it should be available (my DE org has it) - key is that you'll have to switch to classic to see it in the `Administrative Reports` folder.

Comment: Got it under classic mode.  But I think this shows last weeks report. And including today's api info.